# How to a fix a broken "Open with"?

Tags: windows, notepad++

How does one fix a broken "Open with" in Windows? Some more detail:

- In the screenshot below, selecting "Open with" does absolutely nothing. This is the case for all file types (not just the .txt file displayed).
- This was originally an issue on a Windows 7 machine. I did an in-place upgrade to Windows 10 thinking that would resolve the issue. No dice.
- Setting default programs makes no difference here
- Many have asked questions about their favorite program not appearing in the list of default programs. I just want to emphasize, that's not the issue here. Open with just doesn't do anything at all.
- MS Tech support suggested re-installing my OS. I'd prefer not doing that again.
- Long-shot: I feel like this has something to do with my Notepad++ install. Selecting "Edit with Notepad++" does nothing either. Also, my Notepad++ install never registered in my list of potential default programs. But I've tried uninstalling and re-installing and had no success :(

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a registry error. Open with context menu is managed in registry in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft \Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\. The open with menu is broken only on your user or in other windows users too ?

Comment: @maudam It's broken for all users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in PDF-XChange Editor version 6.0.318.0, here is the bug report: https://www.tracker-software.com/forum3/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=26987

Version 6.0.318.1 which was released a few days later solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Either PDFTools6 or the combination of PDFTools6 and Notepad++ put my machine in a wonky state. I uninstalled both Notepad++ and PDFTools6 (which included PDFXChange Editor). Problem solved. I re-installed both without issue.